# How to count text inside an array?

Tags: php, mysql

In my MySQL table (userdata) there's a column named "options". In that column user responses are stored after they complete a quiz.
Sample data pertaining to a user is given below:

```
{"correctness":{"question_id_209":false,"question_id_208":true,"question_id_207":true,"question_id_206":false,"question_id_205":true},"user_answered":{"question_id_209":"830","question_id_208":"826","question_id_207":"822","question_id_206":"818","question_id_205":"815"},"passed_time":"13 seconds","user_points":3,"max_points":5,"attributes_information":[],"calc_method":"by_correctness"}
```

Now I want to search this array for the word "true" and want to count the word.
I started with this, but don't know what to do next:

```
 $query="SELECT options FROM userdata WHERE user_id=1";
 $result= mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

Comment: this is a json datatype sxo search for it, and try to explain better what you exactly mean by counting text

Comment: By not storing JSON and making a proper database structure.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only count how many correct answers the user had for display purposes, here is what you should do following your example:

```php
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$data = json_decode($row['options'], true);

$correctAnswers = array_filter($data['correctness'], function($question) {
    return $answer === true;
});

$total = count($correctAnswers);
```

But if you want to do a SQL query, then it would be more complicated. For that you might want to take a look at this page:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html

I hope it helps.